# Search one text file for values of another and then print that line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm looking for some python code that will take values from textfile1.txt and then search each line in textfile2.txt and return any LINE that contains the value from textfile1.txt.  To give you an example:

```
textfile1.text contains:
Chad
Flash
Arrow

textfile2.text contains:
Who is awesome? Chad
Fastest human alive? Flash
Looks good in green? Arrow
```

As soon as the content from textfile1 is found, I need it to print the previous line of code from textfile2.  The way this particular database is set up, the values from textfile1 will always appear at the end of the line in textfile2.  I've tried a number of things but I just can not get this to work.  This is the closest I've come to getting *any* results:

```
with open("textfile2.txt") as f:
  x = f.read()

with open("textfile1.txt") as f:
  for i in (line.strip() for line in f):
    if i in x:
      print(i, ', found.')
```

Here are the results:

```
[Chad] , found.
[Flash] , found.
[Arrow] , found.
```

I tried flipping textfile1 and textfile2 but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm not even sure if this is something that can be done but I figured I'd ask here before giving up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just print the line as well:

```
with open('textfile2.txt') as f:
   words = [line.strip() for line in f]

with open('textfile1.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.split(' ')[-1].strip() in words:
         print(line)
```

I am splitting each line at a space, as a cheap way of getting all the words:

```
>>> s = 'Who is awesome? Chad'
>>> s.split(' ')[-1]
'Chad'
```

Comment: I had to flip the files (that was probably my own fault) but this did the trick!!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: So they've come back to me reporting that their log file they want to scan puts a black space after each line.  For some reason, this is causing the code you gave me not to return results.  If I go into the log files and delete that blank space after each line, the code above works.  Any idea?  To use my files as an example: [Chad] returns but [Chad]*BLANKSPACE* does not.

Answer (score 0):

Print the line instead of `print (i)`;

```
print(line, ', found.')
```

Because `i` is the word here, you want to print line,not word.